Is there is a Build failed in my react native app?How to solve it
When i want to build my react native app.This error is displayed
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'example'.


Could not determine the dependencies of null.
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.facebook.react:react-native:0.66.3.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.66.3/react-native-0.66.3.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.66.3/react-native-0.66.3.pom
Required by:
project :

How to solve this build error in my react native app

What Java version are you using?

I used java 19.0.2 version

I found some potential fixes on github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210
